# How is Bitcoin / Litecoin mining prize awarded when solo mining?

Tags: litecoin, solo-mining

When solo mining and connecting to either the Bitcoin-QT server or Litecoin-QT server.  If I actually do find a solution to the block, how is that prize awarded? I have not shared my public key via bfgminer, eg:
`bfgminer -o http://127.0.0.1:8336 -u bitcoinrpc -p ........`

How does the bitcoin/litecoin network know which public key to credit? Or does the credit just appear in the bitcoin/litecoin wallet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first transaction in a block, "creates" an amount of new bitcoins. The miner of that block puts the address there, so it can make sure it's an address he has access to.

Most solo miners are connected to a bitcoind daemon. Whenever they find a block, the new address containing the block reward is added to their wallet.

When you run bfgminer, you give it access to bitcoind through your RPC login, so it will add the address to your wallet.